# Progress Bar That Changes Text And Pictures

Tags: c#, progress-bar, label

I am making a project in C#. I am trying to get a label and a picture to change when the progress bar reaches a certain point. The step is 10 and the maximum is 5000. So far I have this

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    pictureBox2.Enabled = true;
    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
    label1.Text = "Scanning";

    this.pictureBox4.Enabled = true;
    this.pictureBox4.Visible = true;
    this.pictureBox3.Enabled = false;
    this.pictureBox3.Visible = false;
    label1.Text = "Threat Detected";

    // ...
```

What I am trying to do is when it reaches 500, for the picture to change and the label to change also.

Comment: In the code that you have posted, there is no reference to a progress bar. Whatever is incrementing your Progress Bar can check for whatever equates to 500 (I imagine it's your timer, so check in the event if it's the 50th tick or the actual value of the bar).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` component, and handle the `Timer.Tick` event:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.PerformStep();

        if (progressBar1.Value == 500)
        {
            // do whatever you want
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, i figured it out, i used if (progressBar1.Value == 99)  
                                   pictureBox1.Visible = true;

etc. thanks though!